# How to get full name of default microphone?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Been trying to get full name of microphone as a variable  on Python for usage of ffmpeg. I have already tried

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
default_device = p.get_default_input_device_info()
print(default_device['name'])
```

and here was the output:

```
Microphone (Conexant SmartAudio         #it was truncated to 31 characters length
```

Obviously,that was truncated and not what i wanted.
Tried sounddevice too:

```
import sounddevice as sd
s = sd.query_devices()
print(s)
```

Output:

```
   0 Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input, MME (2 in, 0 out)
>  1 Microphone (Conexant SmartAudio, MME (2 in, 0 out)           #still truncated
   2 Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output, MME (0 in, 2 out)
<  3 Speakers (Conexant SmartAudio H, MME (0 in, 2 out)
   4 Primary Sound Capture Driver, Windows DirectSound (2 in, 0 out)
   5 Microphone (Conexant SmartAudio HD), Windows DirectSound (2 in, 0 out)    #now got normal,but why?
   6 Primary Sound Driver, Windows DirectSound (0 in, 2 out)
   7 Speakers (Conexant SmartAudio HD), Windows DirectSound (0 in, 2 out)
   8 Speakers (Conexant SmartAudio HD), Windows WASAPI (0 in, 2 out)
   9 Microphone (Conexant SmartAudio HD), Windows WASAPI (2 in, 0 out)
  10 Stereo Mix (Conexant HD Stereo Mix), Windows WDM-KS (2 in, 0 out)
  11 Microphone (Conexant HD Audio capture), Windows WDM-KS (2 in, 0 out)
  12 Speakers (Conexant HD Audio output), Windows WDM-KS (0 in, 2 out)
```

It can be seen that device number 1 was my default one and if that was full name it would be perfect but unfortunately that was not.

Then the only thing i could have thought of was to capture full name from list that ffmpeg provided:

```
'ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy':
[dshow @ 000001cc4f298d00] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 000001cc4f298d00]  "USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam"
[dshow @ 000001cc4f298d00]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_13d3&pid_5a07&mi_00#6&2f27e633&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 000001cc4f298d00]  "screen-capture-recorder"
[dshow @ 000001cc4f298d00]     Alternative name "@device_sw_{860BB310-5D01-11D0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86}\{4EA69364-2C8A-4AE6-A561-56E4B5044439}"
[dshow @ 000001cc4f298d00] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 000001cc4f298d00]  "Microphone (Conexant SmartAudio HD)"
[dshow @ 000001cc4f298d00]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{AFE404CD-A721-49BE-8AC5-669DA725185F}"
[dshow @ 000001cc4f298d00]  "virtual-audio-capturer"
[dshow @ 000001cc4f298d00]     Alternative name "@device_sw_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\{8E146464-DB61-4309-AFA1-3578E927E935}"
```

I used

```
popen = subprocess.Popen('ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
popen.wait()

lines = popen.stdout.readlines()
print(lines)
```

After that i got totally confused because the output was an empty list. Now i am lost in desert and know nowhere to go. Really appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: Are you running code with root user?

Comment: I'm not sure with that.How can i know if i am?

Comment: Try adding shell=True option in your subprocess.                                          
"popen = subprocess.Popen('ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)"

Comment: Been busy these days and spent no time on it. But thank you for helps anyway.